# Accessing Categories and Keywords from metadata of a Component in event code of Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, event-system

In event code for Tridion 2011 `OnPagePublishPost` method, I want to get Category and Keywords value from **Metadata** of a Component.  The metadata field in the Schema is as below:

Field Type : Text

The Checkboxes  **Values will be Selected from a List** and **Category** are checked.

List Type: Checkboxes

I have created a Category called "Sections" and have added Keywords to it.  Those Keywords show as checkboxes in the Component.  I want to get the Keyword values from the Component.  The code which I have written is :

```
Component compSource = null;
//page is the object of Page and is passed in the parameter.
compSource = page.ComponentPresentations[0].Component;     

ItemFields fieldsMetaCommon = new ItemFields(compSource.Metadata,
compSource.MetadataSchema); 
//Getting section keywords 
//pr_section is a field in MetaDataDesign of the schema with Type as Text and with the configuration of  values will be selected from list and Categories checked.

KeywordField fieldSection = (KeywordField)fieldsMetaCommon["pr_section"];
Keyword fieldSectionkeyword = fieldSection.Value;
```

In component Metadata, I have selected a category and the keywords related to it are 6 as of nowand they are checkboxes, which means that the component will be tagged with multiple keywords.
I am not sure how will I loop through the keywords as they are multiple. Nickoli gave me the code but i assume it will work for only a single keyword in a category.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Tridion 2011 and you have the OnPagePublishPost method, then you're using the legacy TOM Event System, not the new TOM.NET based Event System.  They have different APIs and one is long deprecated.

If you want to do this with TOM.NET then the code would be something like this:

Assuming you've figured out how to get your Component object in question, you would use the ItemFields API to pull the Keyword fields:

```
KeywordField myKewordFieldInComponent = (KeywordField)fields["MyField"];
Keyword myKeyword = myKewordFieldInComponent .Value;
if (myKeyword!= null)
{
    ItemFields myKeywordsMetaFields = new   ItemFields(myKeyword.Metadata, myKeyword.MetadataSchema);
    if (myKeywordsMetaFields.Contains("MyKeywordMetaField"))
    {
        string metafieldText = ((TextField)myKeywordsMetaFields["MyKeywordMetaField"]).Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using TOM.NET. I will try the code and update if it works for me.

Comment: My category has multiple keywords as those are checkboxes in the component metadata.So i need to loop through all the keywords. How can i do that?

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: Instead of using .Value use .Values.  Take a look at the API for these details.  Intellisense in Visual Studio can also go a long way.

Comment: I tried but it shows as issue. Intellisense does not give much idea and so i raised this. As per you I changed to values but it is giving error-        Keyword fieldSectionkeyword = fieldSection.Values;

Comment: Can anybody help me on this please?

Comment: Any help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

```
KeywordField fieldSection = (KeywordField)fieldsMetaCommon["pr_section"];
Keyword fieldSectionkeyword = fieldSection.Value;

//This fieldSectionkeyword  gave the tcm id

//The below line gave the text of the keyword.
fieldSectionkeyword.Title.ToString()
```

Comment: It doesn't explained, what you fixed

Comment: @Siva- I was facing issue in getting the keyword text from a category, so if u see the above three lines, line 1 gave the tcm of the keyword, line 2 is not required but you can assume that it was the part of the solution nickoli gave, and line 3 gives the value of the keyword which i wanted.